# Translate variables from JavaScript to PHP within HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I create certain variables within JavaScript which I can then access in PHP code? For example, I could post a variable from JavaScript to a new variable within PHP.

```
<script>

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
var myvariable = document.getElementById("text").value;
}

</script>

<?php

$variable = [should be equal to variable created within javascript]

?>
```

Comment: AJAX is the basic answer, php has finished before any js begins,

Comment: @smith Do you mean that there is a "document.getElementById("text").value" equivalent direct to PHP?

Comment: No, what he's saying is PHP produces HTML **before** the javascript ever runs. The only way you can get "javascript to **TELL** PHP anything (like variables) is to send it via AJAX.